# Generic Vault Policy for Kubernetes Services

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I was trying to implement a generic rule that will allow each Kubernetes service to access it’s own path. This is what I tried:

```
path "secret/services/k8s/{{identity.entity.metadata.metadata.service_account_namespace}}/{{identity.entity.metadata.metadata.service_account_name}}/*" {
  capabilities = ["read"]
}
```

But this does not work - anyone managed to write such a generic policy that works?

What I tried so far?

- Using both entity metadata and the Kubernetes accessor
- Ensure I am using the right service account by inspecting it's token
- Check with static path (replace the template with the actual values) - worked

Comment: Have you read this documentation https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/identity-access-management/vault-agent-k8s ?

Comment: Yep, does the documentation explain how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending some time, I was able to find the answer:

```
path "kv-v2/data/kubernetes/{{identity.entity.aliases.<kubernetes auth accessor>.metadata.service_account_namespace}}/{{identity.entity.aliases.<kubernetes auth accessor>.metadata.service_account_name}}" {
  capabilities = ["read"]
}
```

To find the accessor, use `vault auth list -detailed`